# Angular 13 type conversion error from backend that returns BLOBs

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, jasper-reports

Angular and node's aren't my strong suits and I've had the misfortune of inheriting an angular 13 project where I'm tasked with implementing a minor JasperReport integration.
To put it brief, 3 different fields from the form are grouped into params that get sent to the backend NODEJS server, which sends it to JasperReports Rest_v2 API which then generates a report with them, however the trouble I'm having is taking return data BLOB and converting it to a PDF file that appears as a file download browser side.

My NODEJS method for connecting to jasper reports rest api:

```
app.post('/api/accounts/report',(req,res)=>{
//Params from the API call
var acc_id = parseInt(req.body.params['acc_id']);
var start_date = req.body.params['start_date'];
var end_date = req.body.params['end_date'];
var sage_num = req.body.params['sage_num'];

var request = require("request");   
qs = require('querystring'),
request = request.defaults({
    jar: true
});
//Login call to jasper server
request.post({url: jasper_login, qs: {j_username:jasper_usr, j_password:jasper_pwd}},
    function(err, resp, body) {
        if(err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }
        //actual report call
        request.get(jasper_hst,
        function (error, response, body1) {
            if (error){
                console.log(response.statusCode);
                console.log(error);
            }
            res.type('arraybuffer').send(response.body);
        })
    }
)
});
```

this method returns the BLOB of data that is the PDF file e.g.:

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T09e1.png)

However the problem I'm having now is a type conversion error as soon as I call the backend:

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T09e1.png)

My ts methods:

```
pdfExportBtn(e:any){
//harcoded params for testing
var params={"acc_id":"18785","start_date":"2022/05/01, 00:00:00","end_date":"2022/06/01, 00:00:00","sage_num":"12341234"};

//call the API and generate report
this.getReport(params).subscribe((response)=>{
  const newBlob = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'}); 
  const downloadLink = document.createElement('a'); 
  downloadLink.target = '_self'; const fileName = acc_name+' Transaction Summary '+date1+' to '+date2+'.pdf'; 
  const data = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob); downloadLink.href = data; 
  downloadLink.download = fileName; document.body.appendChild(downloadLink); 
  downloadLink.click();
});
}

getReport(params){
    return this.http.post<Blob>(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/accounts/report`,{responseType: 'arraybuffer'},{params});
}
```

But I'm specifying the return types as a blob and the 'array buffer' so I have no clue why its trying to parse into JSON.

Comment: Angular is still trying to parse your response. Try with `{ responseType: 'blob' }` instead.

Comment: That results in a blank PDF file being generated though, so data seems to be mangled somewhere along the line.